Express.js Stripe Webhook Route Returning 404 Error Despite Correct Configuration
Summary
I am developing an Express.js application to handle Stripe webhooks. Despite configuring the webhook route as recommended, I keep encountering a 404 Not Found error when Stripe attempts to post events to my webhook endpoint.
Environment

Node.js Version: [v20.14.0]
Express Version: [4.18.2]
Stripe Version: [1.19.5]

Issue Description
When I run the Stripe CLI to forward events to my local server, I receive a 404 Not Found error for each event. Below are the details of the error messages:
2024-06-09 16:30:24   --> invoice.paid [evt_1PPfGkRsJfE0QDMT8OOiGWVh]
2024-06-09 16:30:24  <--  [404] POST http://localhost:3080/webhook [evt_1PPfGkRsJfE0QDMT8OOiGWVh]

Server Code (index.js)

javascript
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const routes = require('./routes');
const webhookRoutes = require('./routes/webhookRoutes');

const { PORT, HOST } = process.env;
const port = Number(PORT) || 3080;
const host = HOST || 'localhost';

const app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '3mb' }));
app.use(mongoSanitize());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '3mb' }));

// Webhook route must handle raw request bodies for signature verification
app.use('/webhook', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), webhookRoutes);

app.use('/api', routes); // Example for other routes

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', '404.html'));
});

app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://${host}:${port}`);
});

Webhook Route (webhookRoutes.js)
javascript
Copy code
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { handleWebhook } = require('../controllers/webhookController');

router.post('/', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), handleWebhook);

module.exports = router;

Webhook Controller (webhookController.js)
javascript
Copy code
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const { updateUserSubscriptionStatus } = require('../../models/userMethods');
const { logger } = require('~/config');

const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET;

const handleWebhook = async (req, res) => {
  logger.info('Received a webhook event');
  let event = req.body;

  // Verify webhook signature
  if (endpointSecret) {
    const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, signature, endpointSecret);
      logger.info('Webhook signature verified');
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error('⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed:', err.message);
      return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }
  }

  try {
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'invoice.paid': {
        const invoice = event.data.object;
        const customerId = invoice.customer;
        logger.info(`Handling invoice.paid for customer ${customerId}`);

        const updateResult = await updateUserSubscriptionStatus(customerId, 'active');
        if (updateResult instanceof Error) {
          logger.error('[updateUserSubscriptionStatus]', updateResult);
          const { status, message } = updateResult;
          return res.status(status).send({ message });
        }

        logger.info('User subscription status updated successfully');
        res.status(200).send('Success');
        break;
      }
      case 'payment_intent.succeeded': {
        const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
        logger.info(`PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} was successful!`);
        res.status(200).send('Success');
        break;
      }
      case 'payment_method.attached': {
        const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
        logger.info('PaymentMethod successfully attached');
        res.status(200).send('Success');
        break;
      }
      default: {
        logger.warn(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
        res.status(400).send(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('[handleWebhook]', err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  handleWebhook,
};

Steps to Reproduce
Start the Server:
node index.js
Use Stripe CLI to Forward Events:
Start Stripe CLI to listen for events and forward them to your local server:
stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:3080/webhook
Trigger a Test Event:
Use Stripe CLI to trigger a test event:
stripe trigger invoice.paid
Expected Behavior
The webhook endpoint should correctly receive and process Stripe events, and the server should log the events and respond with a 200 status code.
Actual Behavior
The server responds with a 404 Not Found error for the webhook endpoint.
Request for Help
I would appreciate any help in diagnosing why the webhook endpoint is not being recognized and how to fix the 404 errors. Thank you!

Have you tried to send a POST request directly to your sever without using Stripe CLI? It's likely that your route config is incorrect.

@yuting I tried curl command: curl -X POST http://localhost:3080/webhook -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"example":"data"}'
and it came in the server logs! as... 2024-06-11 17:01:54 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ''', "'{example:data}'" is not valid JSON
2024-06-11 17:01:54     at JSON.parse ()
2024-06-11 17:01:54     at createStrictSyntaxError (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:169:10)... Where would I check my route config?

You should use the body parser middleware after the webhook route

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
